# How to solve $x^TAy = d$, with $x$, $y$ in constraints, and $A$, $d$ are known.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

**Problem** is to solve $x^TAy = d$, where $A$ and $d$ are known, $x$ and $y$ remain unknown.
$x$ and $y$ are vectors; $A$ is a matrix; $d$ is a scalar. There are constraints for $x$ and $y$, requiring $x$ and $y$ sums up to 1, and all elements greater equal than zero, i.e., $x^T \mathbf{1} = 1, x \geq \mathbf{0}$ and $y^T \mathbf{1} = 1, y \geq \mathbf{0}$

**My solution** is to develop it as an optimization problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min x^TAy -  d\\
&\text { s.t. } \begin{aligned}
& \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{n}}=1, \mathbf{x} \geq 0, \mathbf{y}^{T} \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{n}}=1, \mathbf{y} \geq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question:** Do you have any other method to make it easier. Can it be solved by a linear system? Still thinking about it.

Comment: But $x^t A y = d$ is not linear in $(x,y)$.

Comment: Why do you think the optimization problem you proposed would give you the desired solution?

Comment: The tough thing is the conditions $\mathbb{x}, \mathbb{y} \ge 0$. Without them, perhaps there may be analytical solution.

Comment: Maybe add one more constraint $x^TAy-d \geq 0$.